# Create sql table from excel spreadsheet c#

Tags: c#, sql, excel

```
Main Section    Section Name Shorted (30 chars max) Attribute Name Shorted (30)
header          header                              versionId
header          header                              serviceId
header          header                              creationTime
header          header                              brandCode
clientProfile   retirementPlanningAnalysis          signifShortFall
clientProfile   retirementPlanningAnalysis          isProjIncAdeq
clientProfile   retirementPlanningAnalysis          howCloseRetire
clientProfile   retirementPlanningAnalysis          clientsView
clientProfile   regularSavingsAndCapitalInvest      suffCashResEmerg
```

I have this table held in excel, i need to create multiple tables in sql from it. Each table will be comprised of the "main section name" plus the "section name". Example: **header_header** or **clientProfile_retirementPlanningAnalysis**. What would be the best way to loop through and create a new table for each unique section name? The columns will come from the Attribute name, so i need to set them into the query too.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you require to run this process once? Several times? Will the structure of the Excel change?

Comment: This is only a one time process, so that i can create a relational model. I've tried adding the data into lists, but i'm not sure of the best way to attach the attributes if i create the table from just one main section row.

Comment: Is the Excel file complicated? can't you build manually the database model once?

Comment: It's going to be around 40 tables looking at the data, probably too time consuming

Answer (score 0):

Consider this excel file to be a DataSource and get the spreadsheet as a DataTable using Oledb in ADO.Net. This way you would get the entire spreadsheet into a DataTable. And do the required processing on the data table. And create the tables in SQL as per the requirement. For your help I have included some code that might help.

```
System.Data.DataTable table1 = new System.Data.DataTable();
            OleDbConnection dbConnection1 =
                    new OleDbConnection
                      (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
                       + @"Data Source=YourFileName.xls;"
                       + @"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;");
            dbConnection1.Open();
            try
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter dbAdapter1 =
                    new OleDbDataAdapter
                        ("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", dbConnection1);
                dbAdapter1.Fill(table1);
            }
            finally
            {
                dbConnection1.Close();
            }
```

This is the best way to read an excel file. Now u can use the DataTable table1 to do the further processing at will.